# load a txt with data, and that data is stored in the fields that I have in the front, using nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

console.log('Executed Before File Reading.');

fs.readFile('C:/Users/jprada/Desktop/BASEII_30-04-2020-053201.ctf', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
    console.log(data);
});

console.log('Executed After File Reading, Probably.');

Comment: Hi, what is the question or issue?

Comment: Hi Chris, I want to load the file and store it in some fields

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask